# iPhone 7 camera - 'heat haze' problem

Tags: iphone, camera

My iPhone 7 (iOS 13.5.1) has developed an intermittent camera problem.  The image I see when I try to take a photo keeps moving in a fluid, wavy way - rather like the distortion you get when you look at a view through an intense heat wave...?  The resultant image, if I take the photo, is blurred.

Comment: is it not Live Photo ?

Comment: No.  The weird thing is how it doesn't happen all the time.  Like, now - at home - it's working fine.  Yesterday on a walk - when I wanted to take photos! - it wasn't.